# Where can I find a local guide for Japan?

Tags: japan, guides

My friends and I are going to Japan in October. A coworker mentioned that there's a site where university students will gladly guide tourists in exchange for transportation/food costs and learning English. He doesn't remember where he found the forum though.

Does anyone know where we can get a local tour guide?

Comment: I posted in chat ("You are here") several months back a link or two to websites where Japanese people do certain tourist activities with you for about $25 or so. If I don't provide you with a link within a week or two, ping me.

Comment: https://www.govoyagin.com was one of the sites I was thinking of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are called Goodwill Guides. Your description is spot on. They only want to have travel etc paid for. But you will not only find students but also retirees and housewives.

I know [one page](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/arrange/travel/guide/list_volunteerGuides_a-n.html) with a huge list. [Here is another one of such sites](http://www.jnto.go.jp/eng/indepth/exotic/JapanesQue/1211/sgg.html) that covers several areas of Japan. If you are in Tokyo, you might want to go directly to [this page](http://www2.ocn.ne.jp/~sgg/index_e.html).